# Can Amazon Elastic Transcoder encode in Microsoft Smooth Streaming format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, smoothing, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Amazon CloudFront now supports Microsoft Smooth Streaming format for delivering adaptive bitrate video. I am just wondering:

Does Amazon Elastic Transcoder have an output setting to transcode to this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesnt yet.

One option is to use AWS transcoder to transform the videos to MP4 and then use [Azure media packager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973635.aspx) to break into streams. You need to build a SQS based task-worker setup using EC2 and handle the second part.